# ADF - Complex nested array in Data Flow

Tags: arrays, json, nested, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I am bit new using Data Flow in ADF so thats why im asking u for help. here's the situation:

I would like to transform a Json file from REST API in Data Flow for creating a tabular/ logical table structure. After transformation i would like to send this data + structure to a Azure SQL Database.

**Here is a overview what i've done:**

Created a Pipeline to copy data from a website to my Data Lake.

[image: Copy Activity]

[image: ADF Pipeline Sink]

This is the input source:

```
{
    "id":[
        {
            "value":40051
        }
    ],
    "uuid":[
        {
            "value":"0ca12ac9-d94b-44cf-a35b-8b7256006cf8"
        }
    ],
    "revision_id":[
        {
            "value":1452381
        }
    ],
    "langcode":[
        {
            "value":"nl"
        }
    ],
    "type":[
        {
            "target_id":"par_chart",
            "target_type":"paragraphs_type",
            "target_uuid":"2c3143a2-bd78-4b4d-afb6-19160de928f2"
        }
    ],
    "status":[
        {
            "value":true
        }
    ],
    "created":[
        {
            "value":"2019-10-17T12:08:05+00:00",
            "format":"Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP"
        }
    ],
    "parent_id":[
        {
            "value":"2561"
        }
    ],
    "parent_type":[
        {
            "value":"node"
        }
    ],
    "parent_field_name":[
        {
            "value":"field_paragraphs"
        }
    ],
    "behavior_settings":[
        {
            "value":[
                
            ]
        }
    ],
    "default_langcode":[
        {
            "value":true
        }
    ],
    "revision_translation_affected":[
        {
            "value":true
        }
    ],
    "content_translation_source":[
        {
            "value":"und"
        }
    ],
    "content_translation_outdated":[
        {
            "value":false
        }
    ],
    "content_translation_changed":[
        {
            "value":"2023-05-09T09:48:38+00:00",
            "format":"Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP"
        }
    ],
    "field_par_chart":[
        {
            "csv":"[[\"\",\"Percentage behandeling\",\"Percentage behandeling\",\"Percentage behandeling\"],[\"2010\",\"19.4\",null,\"\"],[\"2011\",\"16.6\",null,\"\"],[\"2012\",\"15.4\",null,\"\"],[\"2013\",\"13.5\",null,\"\"],[\"2014\",\"13\",null,\"\"],[\"2015\",\"13\",null,\"\"],[\"2016\",\"14.1\",null,\"\"],[\"2017\",\"17.7\",null,\"\"],[\"2018\",\"24\",null,\"\"],[\"2019\",\"\",\"27.7\",\"\"],[\"2020\",\"\",\"31.9\",\"\"],[\"2021*\",\"\",\"\",\"42.9\"],[\"2022*\",null,\"\",\"46.2\"]]",
            "csv_url":"",
            "config":"{\"chart\":{\"type\":\"line\",\"renderTo\":{\"hcEvents\":{\"mousedown\":[{\"order\":null}],\"touchstart\":[{\"order\":null}],\"mouseover\":[{\"order\":null}],\"mouseout\":[{\"order\":null}]},\"__EV_STORE_KEY@7\":{}}},\"xAxis\":[{\"type\":\"category\",\"index\":0,\"isX\":true}],\"yAxis\":[{\"title\":{\"text\":\"Percentage\",\"offset\":-81.859375},\"min\":0,\"tickInterval\":5,\"index\":0,\"events\":{}}],\"templateName\":\"lineBasic\",\"series\":[{\"type\":null,\"animation\":false,\"data\":[{\"name\":\"2010\",\"y\":19.4},{\"name\":\"2011\",\"y\":16.6},{\"name\":\"2012\",\"y\":15.4},{\"name\":\"2013\",\"y\":13.5},{\"name\":\"2014\",\"y\":13},{\"name\":\"2015\",\"y\":13},{\"name\":\"2016\",\"y\":14.1},{\"name\":\"2017\",\"y\":17.7},{\"name\":\"2018\",\"y\":24},{\"name\":\"2019\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2020\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2021*\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2022*\",\"y\":null}],\"name\":\"Percentage behandeling\",\"_colorIndex\":0,\"_symbolIndex\":0},{\"type\":\"line\",\"animation\":false,\"data\":[{\"name\":\"2010\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2011\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2012\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2013\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2014\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2015\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2016\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2017\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2018\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2019\",\"y\":27.7},{\"name\":\"2020\",\"y\":31.9},{\"name\":\"2021*\",\"y\":null},{\"name\":\"2022*\",\"y\":null}],\"name\":\"Percentage behandeling\"},{\"type\":\"line\",\"animation\":false,\"data\":[{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2010\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2011\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2012\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2013\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2014\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2015\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2016\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2017\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2018\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2019\"},{\"y\":null,\"name\":\"2020\"},{\"y\":42.9,\"name\":\"2021*\"},{\"y\":46.2,\"name\":\"2022*\"}],\"name\":\"Percentage behandeling\"}],\"title\":{\"text\":\"Trend in wachttijden voor behandeling in ziekenhuis langer dan de Treeknorm\"},\"legend\":{\"enabled\":false}}"
        }
    ],
    "field_par_extra_info":[
        {
            "value":"singlecard"
        }
    ],
    "field_par_hidden":[
        {
            "value":false
        }
    ],
    "field_par_text":[
        {
            "value":"<ul>\r\n\t<li><em>Door meerdere veranderingen van de bron en methode zijn de percentages van 2010-2018, 2019-2020 en 2021-2022 niet goed met elkaar te vergelijken.</em></li>\r\n\t<li><em><span><span><span>De wachttijden van 2021 zijn enkel gebaseerd op wachttijden gemeten van augustus&nbsp;2021 t/m december&nbsp;2021 vanwege een verandering in de methode. In de eerste helft van 2021 was 28,7% van de wachttijden voor behandeling langer dan de treeknorm.</span></span></span></em></li>\r\n\t<li><em>In 2020 brak de coronapandemie uit. Hiermee moet rekening worden gehouden bij het interpreteren van de trends.</em></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Bron&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;<br />\r\nWachttijdenonderzoek, Mediquest<br />\r\nWachttijdenregistratie NZa<br />\r\n<strong>Verslagjaar&nbsp; t/m</strong><br />\r\n2022<br />\r\n<strong>Laatste update gegevens&nbsp;</strong><br />\r\n24 mei 2023<br />\r\n<strong>Updatefrequentie&nbsp;</strong><br />\r\nJaarlijks<br />\r\n<strong>Meer info</strong><br />\r\n<a href=\"https://www.vzinfo.nl/prestatie-indicatoren/wachttijd-langer-dan-treeknorm-behandeling\" target=\"_blank\">Prestatie-indicatoren gezondheidszorg op VZinfo.nl</a></p>\r\n",
            "format":"volledige_html",
            "processed":"<ul><li><em>Door meerdere veranderingen van de bron en methode zijn de percentages van 2010-2018, 2019-2020 en 2021-2022 niet goed met elkaar te vergelijken.</em></li>\n\t<li><em><span><span><span>De wachttijden van 2021 zijn enkel gebaseerd op wachttijden gemeten van augustus 2021 t/m december 2021 vanwege een verandering in de methode. In de eerste helft van 2021 was 28,7% van de wachttijden voor behandeling langer dan de treeknorm.</span></span></span></em></li>\n\t<li><em>In 2020 brak de coronapandemie uit. Hiermee moet rekening worden gehouden bij het interpreteren van de trends.</em></li>\n</ul><p><strong>Bron </strong> <br />\nWachttijdenonderzoek, Mediquest<br />\nWachttijdenregistratie NZa<br /><strong>Verslagjaar  t/m</strong><br />\n2022<br /><strong>Laatste update gegevens </strong><br />\n24 mei 2023<br /><strong>Updatefrequentie </strong><br />\nJaarlijks<br /><strong>Meer info</strong><br /><a href=\"https://www.vzinfo.nl/prestatie-indicatoren/wachttijd-langer-dan-treeknorm-behandeling\" target=\"_blank\">Prestatie-indicatoren gezondheidszorg op VZinfo.nl</a></p>\n\n"
        }
    ],
    "field_par_text_bgcolor":[
        {
            "value":"bg-gray-lightest"
        }
    ],
    "field_par_text_position":[
        {
            "value":"below"
        }
    ],
    "field_par_title":[
        {
            "value":"Trend "
        }
    ],
    "field_par_title_class":[
        
    ],
    "field_par_title_enable":[
        {
            "value":false
        }
    ],
    "field_par_title_tag":[
        {
            "value":"h4"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the sink part of ADF Pipeline:

Its saved in the data lake as a .json file.

[image]

**Important: i only need to transform this  part of the Json element:**
field_par_chart  with "csv" element

[image]

The expected data structure must be like this (see image below) and saved as a text file.

[image]

Any suggestions how to do this with a ADF Pipeline and/or ADF Data Flow?

Many thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Is there any limitation that you should only use dataflow and not any of copy activity or lookup?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula thanks for your reply. No there is no limitation except my experience

Comment: `"csv":"[[\"\",\"Percentage behandeling\"`, here your first column name is not mentioned. But In your expected output it is there is `Category`. Is your JSON missed it when providing the question or you want to add that column name manually?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula want to add the column Category manually.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula Thanks for your suggestions. While creating a Dataflow..first challenge appearswhen i using "Data Preview". 
It says: "at Source 'Input': Malformed records are detected in schema inference. Parse Mode: FAILFAST. It could be because of a wrong selection in document form to parse json file(s). Please try a different 'Document form' (Single document/Document per line/Array of documents) on the json source.".   i tried every option from Document form (single doc / doc per line / array of docs). 
Did you change the default options on the first step of dataflow?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula i deleted existed dataflow and created a new one. The error doesnt appeared thanks

Comment: I took the same JSON that you provided in a file, and I have selected Single document in JSON settings of Source options. You can see, it detected the schema and working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target columns are limited and column names are known, then you can try the below approach.

In your expected output, 3 columns have same name, ADF or SQL won't support these. So, I have ignored the first array(column names array) from the `field_par_chart` field.

As you want the data only from `field_par_chart` field, remove the remaining fields from the source using **select** transformation.

[image]

Then I took 3 dervied column transformations.

**derived column1:**

It splits the string and generates **array of arrays** with below dynamic expression.

```
map(split(replace(field_par_chart_csv,'[',''),'],'),split(replace(replace(#item,'"',''),']',''),','))
```

[image]

**derived column2:**

**It skips the first sub array**(array of column names) due to the same column names and unfolds all the sub arrays and converts them into rows like below using this dynamic expression.

```
unfold(slice(arr,2))
```

[image]

**derived column3:**

It generates the required columns from the row arrays. Here, I am giving the column names manually and **converting the values from string to double**. you can give whatever column names you want manually.

[image]

In the **sink**, give your target SQL table and give the mapping for only those 4 columns and remove the extra columns that we got from previous transformations.

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

Execute this dataflow by pipeline and you can load this data to your target SQL table.

**My Dataflow JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn3"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          id as (value as integer)[],",
                "          uuid as (value as string)[],",
                "          revision_id as (value as integer)[],",
                "          langcode as (value as string)[],",
                "          type as (target_id as string, target_type as string, target_uuid as string)[],",
                "          status as (value as boolean)[],",
                "          created as (value as string, format as string)[],",
                "          parent_id as (value as string)[],",
                "          parent_type as (value as string)[],",
                "          parent_field_name as (value as string)[],",
                "          behavior_settings as (value as string[])[],",
                "          default_langcode as (value as boolean)[],",
                "          revision_translation_affected as (value as boolean)[],",
                "          content_translation_source as (value as string)[],",
                "          content_translation_outdated as (value as boolean)[],",
                "          content_translation_changed as (value as string, format as string)[],",
                "          field_par_chart as (csv as string, csv_url as string, config as string)[],",
                "          field_par_extra_info as (value as string)[],",
                "          field_par_hidden as (value as boolean)[],",
                "          field_par_text as (value as string, format as string, processed as string)[],",
                "          field_par_text_bgcolor as (value as string)[],",
                "          field_par_text_position as (value as string)[],",
                "          field_par_title as (value as string)[],",
                "          field_par_title_class as string[],",
                "          field_par_title_enable as (value as boolean)[],",
                "          field_par_title_tag as (value as string)[]",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1",
                "select1 derive(arr = map(split(replace(field_par_chart_csv,'[',''),'],'),split(replace(replace(#item,'\"',''),']',''),','))) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "source1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          field_par_chart_csv = field_par_chart[1].csv",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "derivedColumn1 derive(new_arr = unfold(slice(arr,2))) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn2 derive(Category = new_arr[1],",
                "          {Percentage behandeling1} = toDouble(new_arr[2]),",
                "          {Percentage behandeling2} = toDouble(new_arr[3]),",
                "          {Percentage behandeling3} = toDouble(new_arr[4])) ~> derivedColumn3",
                "derivedColumn3 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:false,",
                "     recreate:true,",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError',",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          Category,",
                "          {Percentage behandeling1},",
                "          {Percentage behandeling2},",
                "          {Percentage behandeling3}",
                "     )) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution works perfectyly fine if i am transforming and loading 3 columns from the Json file source. But what happened if i have a Json file source that have 4 columns? Do i need manually add the 4th column in the step "derived column3:"??? 
My wish is to have a generic step in your Dataflow. any suggestins?

Comment: whatever the columns, if you know the column names, you can add them manually like `new_arr[5]` for 5th column. AFAIK, In this kind of cases where the JSON resides in string, there might not be a generic solution in ADF.